# Does a oracle query performance depends on DB users?

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, database-performance

I have two users - user1,user2.

Both have been given a Grant of select on a view say view1 created by some other user say manager1.

Now user1 and user2 both have created synonym on the manager1's view so that they don't require to query using `manager1.view_name` but just using `view name`.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE SYNONYM user1.view_name1 FOR manager1.view_name1;
```

Now My question is the same query is taking much longer time when executed under user1 but is taking less than a second when executed under user2.

I tried different combinations and different order of execution to avoid caching issues. But in vain. Please help.

Taking around 10 seconds under user1. :(

Comment: they are different queries as text differ for at least one character. See the execution plans of both queries and force the bad to follow the execution plan of the good. We can help you if you post both execution plans and the query.

Comment: check with your dbas to see if VPD/rls policy is enabled on the view (just a guess)

Comment: @FlorinGhita : They are exactly the saem query. And both has same 'PLAN HASH VALUE'

Comment: the queries should return the same data? Or the result depends on user?

Comment: Queries are returning same data but was taking different times..It seems fine now. SO you can close the question.

Comment: @Anubhab If this was just a testing fluke (don't feel bad, we've all done it) maybe you should delete this question.

Answer (score 1):

There are various reasons why same the SQL statement(exactly same text) can have different execution plans. This can be either an Oracle bug or a difference in the "environment". For example different datatypes for placeholders, different NLS_ parameters (sorting, case sensitivity).